# How to modify URL for Wordpress in config files, not through the Admin Console

Tags: php, wordpress, configuration

My Wordpress site has an incorrect URL so when I access the domain "phoenixadultsoccerleague.com" it doesn't work.  You'll see "Home" and "About" links.  When you hover over those links you'll see a different URL.

How can I go into the configuration files and update the URL so the Wordpress site will come up?  It should be pointing to "phoenixadultsoccerleague.com"  Is it in the DB files or the PHP files in the file structure?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to edit the wp_configuration table in your DB. The site domain is written there.

After that, you would have a working wordpress, but I suggest you to run also the domain edit by your control panel: it will do a bunch of stuff that is very tedius if done "by hand"

Answer (score 0):

You may do this through the WordPress database. 
Open the database and look for wp_optio ns and then " home URL" and "Site URL".

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO, I suggest that you first read [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)